# read uploaded file name in java

Tags: java, file-upload

I have uploaded a file in java, and I am trying something like this to get the uploaded file name

```java
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
System.out.println("File name: " + uploadedFile.getName());
```

and it is printing the filename along with its path relative to Computer as:

```
File name: E:\Grievances Project\Feb 2012 data\22439-29-02-2012\22439-29-02-2012.xls
```

how can i get only the uploaded file name irrespective of the place from where it is being uploaded like :

```
File name: 22439-29-02-2012.xls
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println(new File(
    uploadedFile.getName()).getName());
```

You might also look through the `String` methods for things like `lastIndexOf("path separator")` and `substring(int,int)`, to handle it in a more generic way.

Comment: String s = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\33.xml";
        System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(System.getProperty("file.separator")) + 1, s.length()));

Comment: @andrew : man i have tried it already but the main problem in using **substring** is as file location changes the file name also changes...
hope you have get it..

Comment: @Uchenna  Great comment.  I'm guessing the OP must not have noticed it!

Comment: @andrew: your both methods are working
I have tried both of them....
thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser. So better to use the sub String methods.

```
String fileName="E:/Grievances Project/Feb 2012 data/22439-29-02-2012/22439-29-02-2012.xls";
System.out.println(fileName.substring((file.lastIndexOf("/")+1), fileName.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;

......

System.out.println("File name: " + (new File(uploadedFile.getName())).getName());
```

Or, simply, use the `getName()` method from `java.io.File`. (I take it that your `getName()` method above is from your own `UploadedFile` class?)

Comment: your method will will work only if i am creating a file and then using the file name.
But unfortunately I have some data inside the file already to read, so i can not use this method.... SORRY
any other method....???

Comment: No, it will work at all times - it's not creating a file, it's just instantiating a File object using the path returned from your function.

Comment: Yes I am really sorry for that 
Actually there was some problem related to my development platform when i restarted my netbeans it worked ...
thanks guys for helping me out!!! :)